# Is it okay to take \$\beta=I_c/I_b=98/2\$ in this problem?

Tags: transistors, npn, homework

> In an npn power transistor the collector current is 20mA. If 98 percent of
>   the electrons injected into base region reach collector then the base
>   current in mA is nearly ?

Here, in this problem is it okay to take \$\beta=I_c/I_b=98/2=49\$ ?

Comment: From what you've posted, you don't need to know \$\beta\$ to answer the question.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding why or how you got \$ 98/2 \$.

Comment: I would keep the image as it was appropriate to visualizing why the solution is what it is.

Comment: @KingDuken Suppose 100 electrons are injected into base then 98 electrons flows into collector and 2 electrons as base current. That is why I took collector current as 98/2 times of base current. I am assuming a common emitter npn amplifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like they mean 98% of the emitter current, not the base current. That means you're given \$\alpha = 0.98\$. You can use that to calculate \$\beta\$ and find the base current.

Comment: \$\beta=\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\$. This is essentially what @2017 already calculated.

Comment: \$\beta=\frac{98}{2}=49\$. Hence, \$I_b=\frac{20}{49} mA\$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know \$\beta\$ to answer the question. Just Kirchoff's Current Law.

Comment: But using beta I get answer directly as \$20/49\$ mA. Is that wrong?

Comment: @ThePhoton How can you solve the question using Kirchoff's law?

Comment: @YashasSamaga, KCL tells you \$I_b + I_e + I_c = 0\$, and the problem statement tells you \$I_e\$ and \$I_c\$ (after a simple calculation).

Comment: @ThePhoton How do you get \$ I_e \$?

Comment: @YashasSamaga, "98 percent of the electrons injected into base [from the emitter] region reach collector", so \$I_c = 0.98 I_e\$.

Comment: Just another way of saying \$\alpha = 0.98\$, but it doesn't require knowing the names "alpha" and "beta", just the very fundamental KCL.

Comment: Well, you could send in a current to the base from the external pin too? The question does not tell that 98% of the emitter current which goes into the base reaches the collector. You could take it as 98% of the base current which enters goes to the collector and the question won't make any sesne.

Comment: @YashasSamaga, No, the three currents must balance, fundamentally by KCL. If 20 mA come out the emitter and only 19.6 mA are going in the collector, then the base current must be 0.4 mA. If you're proposing that the device is in some other operating mode so that there's no implication that "98% of the electrons injected into the base reach the collector" means \$I_c=19.6\rm{mA}\$, then the other answer, using parameters defined for forward active operation, is also incorrect. And in fact without this inference there's not enough information to answer the question.

Comment: Also, the condition of 98% of emitter current reaching the collector is only consistent with forward active operation. Or with very weak saturation in which case both answers given would still apply.

Comment: So the question is wrong without correcting "If 98 percent of the electrons injected into base region reach collector"?

Comment: No, "98% of the electrons injected into base region reach the collector" is part of the problem statement. There's no reason to think it's an impossible condition. Based on this fact you've been told, you need to figure out what the base current is, and two answers have shown two different ways to do that. (or two different ways of looking at the same solution)

Comment: @YashasSamaga, when an NPN BJT is in forward active mode, electrons are injected from the emitter into the base. A large majority of these are swept across to the collector (where they form the collector current). A small fraction recombine in the the base, where they form the base currents. These "collector current" and "base current" are the same currents that must ultimately be supplied by current flowing in to the pins of the transistor.